# Compressed Folder Wizard - other archive formats

Tags: compression, zip, archiving, rar, shell-extensions

Anybody know of a shell extension to make other archive formats, such as RAR, work with Windows' built-in Compressed Folder Wizard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The api for the Compressed Folder Wizard is undocumented. There are several archivers with shell extensions that far exceed the Compressed Folder Wizard's capabilities though. Many of them free.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_archivers#Archiver_features

Answer (score 1):

Nope. However, [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) and [winRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/) both have their own shell extensions which include options such as Extract here (extracts to the current directory) and extract to *archivename/* (extracts to a folder with the same name as the archive) in the right click menu.